# Local context placement in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In order to reduce the number of scripts to load when requesting the first time a Next.js app, I would like to avoid having only one general context/context provider and have some local contexts managing states that do not exist a priori.

For example, having a home context managing states inside the /home part of the tree.

I imagine that it has to be placed at /home but have no idea where the tree can be wrapped.

```
-| pages
 |-| _app.js      //where the global state lives
 |-| index.js     //root of Next.js app
 |-| home         //where the local state should live ?
 |-|-| news.js
 |-|-| index.js
 | contexts
 |-| GlobalContext.js
 |-| HomeContext.js
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: You should wrap the `_app.js` component with your contexts and access them globally

Comment: Do you mean you want a context provider that would be shared between `/home/index.js` and `/home/news.js`?

Comment: Precisely, because you will have to be authenticated to go to /home, from what I understand there is no benefits to load all /home logic in the global context in order to reduce first load on connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question.

From what I've learned there are no ways to wrap a part of the application in a local context.

Nevertheless from the tests I've done if you wrap your app with another context it does not augment significantly the size of the script to load on every page, merely few percents, because most of it is for the DOM manipulations of React.

So I went for multiple contexts, as stated, and imported them in the pages where they were useful, it does augment the bundle of 2-3% in my case which I consider negligible.

---

Update Next 13.4

This is easily feasible now as we have intermediary layouts.
For example, consider this architecture.

```
-- app
  -- layout.js  // Root layout
  -- page.js    // Index page
  -- dashboard
    -- DashboardContext.jsx
    -- page.js
    -- layout.js
    -- user
    -- entreprise
```

Here, if we insert DashboardContext as a wrapper in `/app/dashboard/layout.js` then we'll have a local context for all dahsboard activities` (what is happening at `/dashboard/user` or `/dashboard/entreprise`)

This behavior is extremely powerfull. This is granular, SEO friendly if context and layout only pass children.